# ng-options doesn't show the ng-model object in the select box on load (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angularjs-select

I have a html select input. Here I use AngularJS:

```
<select class="form-control" 
    ng-model="t.selected" 
    ng-options="option | matriseValgFilter for option in t.Valgalternativer" 
    ng-change="change(t.selected)">
</select>
```

Problem is that t.select is defined, but it does not show up in the html select listbox. If I select something, then t.select changes and the displayed value changes correctly, I want it to display the t.select on load.

This is the angular code, made a fiddle to illustrate better: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fiddlejan/Lt0cuwLd/

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])

.controller('controller', function($scope) {

  $scope.t = {
    "Tabellnavn": "BE3.2:1",
    "Siffer": "x",
    "Stikkord": "Utvendig kledning:",
    "Tekst": {
      "Format": 0,
      "Content": "{Matrise BE3.2:1}"
    },
    "Merknader": null,
    "Delprodukter": null,
    "Valgalternativer": [{
      "Siffer": "-",
      "Tekst": "{Matrise BE3.2:1}",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": null,
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "00",
      "Tekst": "Valgfri",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": null,
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "11",
      "Tekst": "Murt forblending",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "NB2.7---x-",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "21",
      "Tekst": "Bordkledning på vegg utvendig – stående bord",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "QK2.11xx---",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "22",
      "Tekst": "Bordkledning på vegg utvendig – stående ukantede bord",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "QK2.12x---",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "23",
      "Tekst": "Bordkledning på vegg utvendig – stående spaltekledning",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "QK2.15xx---",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "24",
      "Tekst": "Bordkledning på vegg utvendig - liggende bord",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "QK2.21xx---",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "26",
      "Tekst": "Platekledning på vertikal flate utvendig utvendig",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "QK5.226--",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "31",
      "Tekst": "Kledning med tynnplatekassetter av kopper",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "SM4.2--",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "32",
      "Tekst": "Kledning med tynnplatekassetter av titansink",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "SM4.3--",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "33",
      "Tekst": "Kledning med tynnplatekassetter av aluminium",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "SM4.4--",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "34",
      "Tekst": "Kledning med tynnplatekassetter av varmforsinket stål",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "SM4.5--",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "35",
      "Tekst": "Kledning med plane metallplater",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "SM5.1",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "88",
      "Tekst": "Uten utvendig kledning",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": null,
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "99",
      "Tekst": "Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": null,
      "Delalternativer": null
    }],
    "selected": {
      "Siffer": "99",
      "Tekst": "Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": null,
      "Delalternativer": null
    }
  };

  $scope.change = function(selected) {
    console.log(selected);
  }
})
.filter('matriseValgFilter', function() {

    return function (option) {

        if (!isNaN(option.Siffer) && option.Kode != null){
            return option.Siffer + ' - ' + option.Tekst + ' (' + option.Kode + ')';
        }

        if (!isNaN(option.Siffer)){
            return option.Siffer + ' - ' + option.Tekst;
        }

        return option.Tekst;


    }
});
```

EDIT: 
To clarify, t.select is set to "99 - Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres" this is what should show on load in the select box.

Answer (score 0):

You need init your variable t.selected like this `$scope.t.selected = $scope.t.Valgalternativer[0];`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/gk8vxmv0/1/).

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])

.controller('controller', function($scope) {
 
  $scope.t = {
    "Tabellnavn": "BE3.2:1",
    "Siffer": "x",
    "Stikkord": "Utvendig kledning:",
    "Tekst": {
      "Format": 0,
      "Content": "{Matrise BE3.2:1}"
    },
    "Merknader": null,
    "Delprodukter": null,
    "Valgalternativer": [{
      "Siffer": "-",
      "Tekst": "{Matrise BE3.2:1}",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": null,
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "00",
      "Tekst": "Valgfri",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": null,
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "11",
      "Tekst": "Murt forblending",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "NB2.7---x-",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "21",
      "Tekst": "Bordkledning på vegg utvendig – stående bord",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "QK2.11xx---",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "22",
      "Tekst": "Bordkledning på vegg utvendig – stående ukantede bord",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "QK2.12x---",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "23",
      "Tekst": "Bordkledning på vegg utvendig – stående spaltekledning",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "QK2.15xx---",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "24",
      "Tekst": "Bordkledning på vegg utvendig - liggende bord",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "QK2.21xx---",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "26",
      "Tekst": "Platekledning på vertikal flate utvendig utvendig",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "QK5.226--",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "31",
      "Tekst": "Kledning med tynnplatekassetter av kopper",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "SM4.2--",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "32",
      "Tekst": "Kledning med tynnplatekassetter av titansink",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "SM4.3--",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "33",
      "Tekst": "Kledning med tynnplatekassetter av aluminium",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "SM4.4--",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "34",
      "Tekst": "Kledning med tynnplatekassetter av varmforsinket stål",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "SM4.5--",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "35",
      "Tekst": "Kledning med plane metallplater",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": "SM5.1",
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "88",
      "Tekst": "Uten utvendig kledning",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": null,
      "Delalternativer": null
    }, {
      "Siffer": "99",
      "Tekst": "Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": null,
      "Delalternativer": null
    }],
    "selected": {
      "Siffer": "99",
      "Tekst": "Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres",
      "Tekst2": null,
      "Kode": null,
      "Delalternativer": null
    }
  };
$scope.t.selected = $scope.t.Valgalternativer[0];
})
.filter('matriseValgFilter', function() {
 
    return function (option) {

        if (!isNaN(option.Siffer) && option.Kode != null){
         return option.Siffer + ' - ' + option.Tekst + ' (' + option.Kode + ')';
        }
        
        if (!isNaN(option.Siffer)){
         return option.Siffer + ' - ' + option.Tekst;
        }
        
        return option.Tekst;
    
    
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="controller as c" style="padding:10px;">

    <select class="form-control" 
        ng-model="t.selected" 
        ng-options="option | matriseValgFilter for option in t.Valgalternativer" >
    </select>

<pre style="margin-top: 10px;">
{{t.selected | json}}
</pre>

  </div>

</body>
```

### Updated

Oh... I understand. You define `t.selected` in your variable `t`. But it doesn't work, because

```
{
  "Siffer": "99",
  "Tekst": "Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres",
  "Tekst2": null,
  "Kode": null,
  "Delalternativer": null
}!= {
  "Siffer": "99",
  "Tekst": "Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres",
  "Tekst2": null,
  "Kode": null,
  "Delalternativer": null
}
```

Another word are not equal.

```
$scope.t.Valgalternativer[$scope.t.Valgalternativer.length-1]!=$scope.t.selected
```

Try this

```
$scope.t.selected = .Valgalternativer[$scope.t.Valgalternativer.length-1];
```

Comment: Well, this changes t.select to the wrong value. Now you reset it to the first element Valgalternativer[0] ({Matrise BE3.2:1}), but the already selected value is "99 - Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres"

Comment: Why do you think, that selected value is "99 - Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres"? In jsfiddle in `{{t.selected | json}}` showing first element  **{Matrise BE3.2:1})** too.

Comment: No it does not, the <pre> shows "99 - Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres". Unless you change it to the first element with ng-init as you do. If you look at the $scope.t.selected the value is "99 - Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres". I don't want this to change on load.

Answer (score 0):

**edit**

As per your comment, for this to work, one way is to set the selected property like this.

```
$scope.t.selected =$scope.t.Valgalternativer[2];
```

*If the object comes from another service or json, you may have to find/filter from t.Valgalternativer and then assign appropriate index.*

This is so because, as pointed out in other answer, if you initialize selected the way you are doing, it will be a new object whose hash value is different.

If you like this approach, please remove the "selected" property from t and add it separately as above. There is no need to change any markup.

**initial**

Try this

```
<select class="form-control" 
    ng-model="t.selected" 
    ng-options="option | matriseValgFilter as option | matriseValgFilter for option in t.Valgalternativer" 
    ng-change="change(t.selected)"
    ng-init='t.selected = "99 - Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres"'>
</select>
```

The viewValue of the option you choose should match with value of one of the options of select.

`as` syntax is used to set value for options in select. Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Comment: Well, the value on load is not always "99 - Annen utvendig kledning – må spesifiseres" or the first value in the array, $scope.t.Valgalternativer[0]. It should be the current t.selected value already defined in scope.

Comment: @ganjan revised the answer as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Object in t.selected and t.Valgalternativer are different according to javascript. Because their hash values are different. Javascript only compare hash values for equality. Only we programmers have to teach Javascript, to compare it with 'Tekst' field instead '$hash'.
Working JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Lt0cuwLd/6/

Below is the only code I have added. It just go through each item in the list and compare its 'Tekst' value with t.selected's 'Tekst' value. If they both equal then, it will return that object and we assign this to t.selected. Now t.selected's '$hash' value also matches and not just 'Tekst'
After all computer is not clever as humans :)

```
$scope.t.selected = $scope.t.Valgalternativer.reduce(function(curr, next){
    if(next.Tekst === $scope.t.selected.Tekst) return next;
    else return curr;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked properly in my actual application, but solved it using a method in the controller that I call with ng-init.

Ended up with this:

```
    <select class="form-control"  
            ng-init="loadMatriseValg(node, t)"
            ng-model="t.selected"
            ng-options="option | matriseValgFilter for option in t.Valgalternativer"
            ng-change="changeMatrise(node, t.selected, '{{t.selected.Kode}}')"></select>
```

Then in the controller I have this:

```
            $scope.loadMatriseValg = function (node, t) {

                // user has not selected anything, set default value
                if (!t.selected) {
                    t.selected = t.Valgalternativer[0];
                }

                // loop through all valg alternativer
                for (var v = 0; v < t.Valgalternativer.length; v++) {

                    if (t.Valgalternativer[v].Siffer == t.selected.Siffer) {

                        t.selected = t.Valgalternativer[v];
                        return;
                    }
                }

            }
```

New fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/fiddlejan/wng2genw/